# How to get smooth mouse events for a canvas "drawing style" app?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make smooth mouse movements across the screen for a drawing style app. More specifically its a "Powder toy". What this means is, it draws pixel by pixel so I cant do some line trickery. I was initially thinking of checking mouse down and mouse up then put something in my game "update" loop to make it draw pixels to the screen but that didnt work out when I found I couldn't directly get the mouse X and mouse Y without the events firing.

So does anyone know a way of smooth mouse movements, the way I have at the moment uses the mousemove event which causes this:

http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/9/26119184415-orig.jpg

(Notice how the pixels are spread apart)

Thank you,

Comment: can you clarify - are you staying that you're trying to create an app so that when you move your mouse around, it draws pixels where the mouse was? And you don't want spaces to show up between pixels?

Comment: Yes, for example if you go on paint and draw with the pencil tool it doesn't miss pixels because it isn't as if it has to wait for an event to re trigger.

Comment: and you don't want to automatically draw lines between the pixels so that they connect?

Comment: I would usually go for that method however the way this is designed it just doesnt allow for it unless I want to slow the app down even further (Already only runs at around 20 fps)

Comment: The easiest way to create a drawing application with canvas is to begin a new path with beginPath() when the mousedown event is triggered, and with the mousemove event you can continually add new points to the path with lineTo() and then fill each tiny line in between each point with the stroke() method.  When the mouseup event is fired, you can stop the drawing.

Comment: but as its based on particle physics it wouldn't work with me drawing lines, basically what's in the screen-shot is particles of sand falling. If I was to draw and join lines it wouldn't act as a individual grain and more like string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your doing a world of sand clone so I imagine you need rects. I used [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to plot the points. Basically `onmousedown` it starts painting. Then `onmousemove` it compares the current coordinates with the last coordinates and plots all of the points between.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/dQppK/4/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    painting = false,
    lastX = 0,
    lastY = 0;

canvas.width = canvas.height = 600;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    if (!painting) {
        painting = true;
    } else {
        painting = false;
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    lastX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    lastY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
};

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (painting) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        // find all points between        
        var x1 = mouseX,
            x2 = lastX,
            y1 = mouseY,
            y2 = lastY;


        var steep = (Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1));
        if (steep){
            var x = x1;
            x1 = y1;
            y1 = x;

            var y = y2;
            y2 = x2;
            x2 = y;
        }
        if (x1 > x2) {
            var x = x1;
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = x;

            var y = y1;
            y1 = y2;
            y2 = y;
        }

        var dx = x2 - x1,
            dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
            error = 0,
            de = dy / dx,
            yStep = -1,
            y = y1;

        if (y1 < y2) {
            yStep = 1;
        }

        for (var x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
            if (steep) {
                ctx.fillRect(y, x, 1, 1);
            } else {
                ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }

            error += de;
            if (error >= 0.5) {
                y += yStep;
                error -= 1.0;
            }
        }



        lastX = mouseX;
        lastY = mouseY;

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to make this demo code. This is exactly what I was after, thanks!

Comment: @TomC No problem I love doing this kind of stuff, good luck on your project.