# Sluggish UI in drawing/sketching web app on Mobile Safari (HTML5 canvas)

Tags: iphone, ios, html, canvas, mobile-safari

We have been playing around with the canvas element, but are encountering sluggishness on Mobile Safari whereas the app works smoothly on the desktop.

The test app is very primitive. It just lets the user draw a line using the mouse on a desktop or a finger on smart phones.

In Mobile Safari, the drawing of the line is often very jerky. The first bit of a line will render in real-time, but the rest won't render until after the finger is lifted from the screen.

Any ideas why?

Code below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>    
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css' />
            <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'></script>
            <script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js'></script>            
            <style type='text/css'>
                #canvas { border:1px solid red }
            </style>        
   </head>

   <body>    
            <div id='draw_page' data-role='page'>
               <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="350"></canvas>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript"> 
              $('#draw_page').live('pageinit', function() {
                prep_canvas();
                });
            </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;
var canvas;
var context;

function prep_canvas() {

canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

}

$('#canvas').live('vmousedown', function(e){
  var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  paint = true;
  addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
  redraw();
});


$('#canvas').live('vmousemove', function(e){
  if(paint){
    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
    redraw();
  }
});


$('#canvas').live('vmouseup', function(e){
  paint = false;
});


function addClick(x, y, dragging)
{
  clickX.push(x);
  clickY.push(y);
  clickDrag.push(dragging);
}


function redraw(){
  canvas.width = canvas.width; // Clears the canvas

  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 2;

  for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++)
  {     
    context.beginPath();
    if(clickDrag[i] && i){
      context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
     }else{
       context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
     }
     context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
     context.closePath();
     context.stroke();
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are not testing on an iPhone emulator. Also running the canvas in fullscreen mode or running as an app ported over with PhoneGap will cause JavaScript in iOS 5 to run like iOS 4.

Comment: Also, there is a way to use multiple layers of canvases to avoid having to redraw everything in each frame, which is very cumbersome in mobile browsers. If you had two canvas layers overtop of one another, you could every so often draw the current line to the canvas in behind and then only draw the newest parts of the line to the canvas in front.

Comment: Wish I could help further. It looks like the answer here has a live demo you could try on your phone and I don't think this person is redrawing the canvas each time:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478501/how-to-get-smooth-mouse-events-for-a-canvas-drawing-style-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/ and it works fluidly on the phone (you'll see a commented out line for img_update() which is used in the two canvas method mentioned by BumbleB2na...but I wasn't using any shapes, just lines, so left it out)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale = 1.0">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone4.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="startup-iphone.png">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {background:#ccc; margin:0; padding:0}
html {margin:0; padding:0;}
#container { position: relative; margin:0; padding:0px; }
#canvas { border: 1px solid #000; background-color:#FFF; position:relative; width:298px; margin-left:11px; margin-top:5px; }
</style>
</head>

<body onload="listen()">
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="298" height="298">
    </canvas><br/>
    <button onclick="clearImage()">Clear</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
if(canvas){var context= canvas.getContext('2d');}
var tool;
tool = new tool_pencil();

document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){ event.preventDefault(); },false);
function listen(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
    if(canvas){
        context= canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";  
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        iphone = ((window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone'))||(window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPod')))?true:false;
        ipad = (window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPad'))?true:false;
        if(iphone||ipad){
            canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchend', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', ev_canvas, false);
        }
        else{
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
        }
    }
}

function tool_pencil () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;
    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        tool.started = true;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started) {
            context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started) {
            tool.mousemove(ev);
            tool.started = false;
            //img_update();
        }
    };
    this.touchstart = function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        tool.started = true;
    };

    this.touchmove = function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        if (tool.started) {
            context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    };

    this.touchend = function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        if (tool.started) {
            tool.started = false;
        }
    };
}

// The general-purpose event handler. This function just determines the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
function ev_canvas (ev) {
    iphone = ((window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone'))||(window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPod')))?true:false;
    ipad = (window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPad'))?true:false;
    if (((iphone)||(ipad))&&(ev.touches[0])){ //iPad
        ev._x = ev.touches[0].clientX;
        ev._y = ev.touches[0].clientY;
    }
    else if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
        ev._x = ev.layerX;
        ev._y = ev.layerY;
    }
    else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
        ev._x = ev.offsetX;
        ev._y = ev.offsetY;
    }
  // Call the event handler of the tool.
    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
        func(ev);
    }
}

function clearImage(){
    var yes=confirm('Clear drawing?');
    if(yes){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";  
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! How did you find this, BTW? Hopefully I can find the answer myself next time. :)

Comment: I think I'd searched for 'canvas paint program' or something comparable...but then I made my own tweaks for touch events. Glad it helped

Comment: Hi @RobotWoods, do you know how we can smooth out the lines drawn with the  pencil tool? There appear jagged and slightly blurry unless the user draws a perfectly straight line, which means drawing smooth circles or curves is impossible.

Comment: Hmm, they're not in my implementation, do you have a lot of other processes going that might slow down the touch move event firing (fewer points==more jagged) also, for the blur, maybe try adjusting width? http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2011/06/18/HTML5-Canvas-Line-Width.aspx

Comment: Nope, not slowed by extra processes. It happens even in the original demo that you based you code on ...

Comment: What device and version are you testing with? My project (which is more that the above piece) works okay on iPhone 4, 4S,iPod touch, and ipad2...but I'll try just the piece above in a few hours and try to replicate

Comment: When you say works okay, it does work okay ... the lines are not horrible, just slightly jagged and not nearly as smooth as other drawing apps. When you draw circles, are the edges perfectly smooth? Maybe we're doing something wrong (though even the original demo contains slightly jagged edges on circles)?

Comment: I do have a bit of pixelation on the edges, I wonder if there's something to be done with retina (since I'm saying my canvas is 300px instead of 600...) I'll have to see whether some sort of scale can be applied (I'm also learning this as I go)...I also haven't used the native iOS drawing, maybe that's better

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9380/discussion-between-robot-woods-and-crashalot)